# Corda: How can I check Consumed or Not Consumed

Tags: corda

How can I check the status of the State (Consumed or Not Consumed) in Corda?

I downloaded Cordapp-example, executed "Create-iou" several times, then I referred to State information using the "ious" API, but I could not confirm the status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the metadata of the state to find out it's consumed or not. in the metadata there is an option to check if the state is consumed or unconsumed.

For example:

```
Vault.Page<YourState> results = rpcOps.vaultQueryByCriteria(linearCriteria, YourState.class);
results.getStatesMetadata().get(0).getStatus(); -> This will get you the status of the state
```

Comment: Thanks to that, I solved it. Just entering the same State does not know that it will not be "cosumed". But I will ask you a question after I investigate it a little more.

Comment: Note that by default, vault query criteria only select unconsumed states. You need to specify in your criteria that you want to select consumed states as well. See https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html#example-usage.